# Developing Cross-Platform/device Compatible Pages

Tags: visualforce, user

How can we differentiate if a VF page is being opened on a Tablet or on any Phone device?
other than "User-agent" and "User agent code" ?

Comment: How would you do it in a normal html page, and why would you do it?

Comment: Right now we are redirecting the page based on iPad or Desktop, we need some generic method to redirect to a different page based device without hard coding the device name in the code.

Comment: To me, it sounds like what you're looking for is a [responsive design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). I'd take a look at using Lightning or [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).